# Simple.data and Casting Logic

Tags: simple.data

I have a Hospital table and the Addresses tables where i have written a simple data query to the DB

```
 db.Hospitals.All().Join(DB.Address,out address).
   Select(db.Hospitals.name,address.PostCode.As(Address.PostCode));
```

The Hospital Model class has Address internally

```
 Class HospitalModel
  {
      public string Name{get;set;}
      public HospitalAddress Address{get;set;}
    }



    public class HospitalAddress
    {
       public string PostCode{get;set;}
     }
```

I am able to get the Name property but the postcode in HospitalAddress  doesn't seem to work. Wondering where this is a problem .

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
db.Hospitals.All().WithAddress();
```

That should eager-load the Address which will make the cast work as expected.

Comment: Table name is Addresses where is the field name is Address

Comment: Then your original query won't work as you're referencing the Addresses table as DB.Address in the Join call. 

Try List<HospitalModel> hospitals = db.Hospitals.All().With(db.Hospitals.Addresses.As("Address"));

Simple.Data does some simple pluralization magic so you can call your table using either the singular or the plural of the table name. Details on that at http://blog.hmobius.com/post/2012/06/23/Name-Resolution-in-SimpleData.aspx.