# Simple.data and nested projection logic

Tags: simple.data

I have table HOSPITALS and ADDRESSES Where ADDRESS_ID is the foreign key . I am using simple.data to get all the details for the class Hospitals which has a Addresses object in it. I am having a query which is like

```
DB.HOSPITALS.All().Select(DB.HOSPITAL.ADDRESSES.POSTCODE);
```

The Postcode is not getting mapped to the Address object propery. basically a problem with the mapping logic for nested object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simple.data and Casting Logic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674470/simple-data-and-casting-logic)

Comment: This appears to be the same question you asked yesterday?

Comment: Ya but this time i am trying to use Select .. It is not casting to the Nested object

Comment: Then use the same advice given yesterday - try `List<HospitalModel> hospitals = db.Hospitals.All().With(db.Hospitals.Addresses.As("Address"));` to wrap it into your POCO

Comment: For With () Keyword i am identifier too long as a error in oracle DB . So i cannot use With really. May be dot notation cast will be a solution. please advice